# Nested Multiple Dropdown Menu - Boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have created a nested drop down menu like this:

[image]

And I have my code for it.

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Products <span class="caret">
</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" href="#">Women <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Blouse</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sweater</a></li>
        </ul>
          ...
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

With my Style

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;}
```

However when I click the drop down button, and click the other drop down, the previous ones doesn't close, therefore it will keep overlap. How do I make the list close it up?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is use jQuery to emulate the user "clicking" anywhere else on the body e.g.

```
$("body").trigger("click");
```